# SwiftUI fails to compile when attempting to filter data using string comparison

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11, swift5

hoping someone can help me out. Been trying to figure out what's going on here with no luck. The app I am building contains the SwiftUI View listed below.

This View is embedded in another View which contains other List's, VStack's, etc. It is called when an item is selected to show another list of data based upon the user's selection.

It all looks, acts and works as intended (without data filtering).

For now, I am using a sample dataSet created using a simple Dictionary of data. When I attempt to apply a filter to this data by string comparison it causes a failure to compile with the following messages:

From Xcode:

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

From Canvas:

> timedOutSpecific(30.0, operation: "a thunk to build")

In addition to these errors, the energy consumption of Xcode skyrockets until failure.

The code listed below will work if I remove the code `self.dataSet == aRecord.module` in the if statement and replace it with `true`. Any time I try to filter my dataset it results in these errors.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DataListView: View {

    @State var titleBar = ""
    @State private var showFavorites = false
    @State private var showPriority = false
    @State var dataSet = ""

    var body: some View {

        List{

            ForEach (sampleData) { aRecord in

                if (((aRecord.isFavorite && self.showFavorites) ||
                    (aRecord.isPriority && self.showPriority) ||
                    (!self.showPriority)) && self.dataSet == aRecord.module ){

                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(titleBar: aRecord.title, statuteData: aRecord.statuteData, isFavorite: aRecord.isFavorite)) {

                            HStack {
                                Text(aRecord.module)
                                    .font(.subheadline)

                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(aRecord.title)
                                }
                                .scaledToFit()

                                Spacer()

                                if aRecord.isFavorite {
                                    Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                                        .imageScale(.small)
                                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle(self.titleBar)
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing:

                        HStack{

                            Button(action: {
                                self.showFavorites.toggle()
                            }) {
                                if self.showFavorites {
                                    Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                                        .imageScale(.large)
                                        .foregroundColor(.yellow).padding()
                                } else {
                                    Image(systemName: "star")
                                        .imageScale(.large).padding()
                                }
                            }

                            Button(action: {
                                self.showPriority.toggle()
                            }) {
                                if self.showPriority {
                                    Text("Priority")
                                } else {
                                    Text("Standard")
                                }
                            }
                    })
                }//endif
            }
        }//end foreach
    }
}

struct TempCode_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DataListView(dataSet: "myDataSetID")
    }
}
```

The reason I believe that the string comparison is the culprit is, for one, it crashes as described above. I have also tried placing the conditional in other places throughout the code with the same results. Any time I apply this type of filter it causes this crash to occur.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe that part of your problem is having titleBar and dataSet as state variables when they don't need to be. If I were writing the code I would use sampleData.filter rather than an if in the closure.

Comment: Thx Michael, I removed all extraneous @State declarations with no improvement..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break out that complex boolean logic into a function outside of the view builder that takes a record and returns a boolean & it should work.

I think the compiler struggles when there is complex logic inside of the body & can't verify return types etc etc.

**Record Verification Function:**

```
func verify(_ record: Record) -> Bool {
    return (((record.isFavorite && showFavorites) ||
    (record.isPriority && showPriority) ||
    (!showPriority)) && dataSet == record.module )
}
```

**Usage In Body:**

```
if self.verify(aRecord) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have just tried this and while I will definitely use this to make things cleaner in the future, it makes the code act stranger.. When I take out all logic, even from the func call, and have it always just return true, the issue persists. So if self.verify(aRecord) always returns true it just locks up (same error messages), however when I just "if true{" it works.. it should be the same thing. So weird..

Comment: Got it working with this idea, I created the function and passed all of the variables I want to test thru to it, then did the logic operations there as you suggested. Not sure why my initial results were not positive however I did reboot along the way, so maybe some junk in there somewhere. This and remove unnecessary @State vars seemed to solve the issue. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I've run into similar issues with complexity inside the view builder. I think it may just be a quirk of the current state of the compiler or a quirk of function builders. Glad you were able to find a solution.